Typescript: Merging partial objects gives a type error
Let's say I have some type T:
type T = {
  a: number;
  b: string;
  c: number;
}

and a constant which partially fulfills T:
const x: Partial<T> = { a: 1, b: "foo" };

I want to reuse this constant to create multiple other constants by filling in missing properties from T:
const y: T = {
  ...x,
  c: 0,
}

const z: T = {
  ...x,
  c: 1,
}

but I get an error from the compiler at the definition of y and z:
Type '{ c: number; a?: number | undefined; b?: string | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  Types of property 'a' are incompatible.
    Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2322)

Which kind of makes sense since x is a Partial, however, it seems that compiler should be able to tell that all fields are provided in the final definition on y and z.
How can I fix this error?

Don’t annotate x? Maybe you want satisfies instead of a type annotation.

"it seems that compiler should be able to tell that all fields are provided in the final definition on y and z", not really. By annotating x as a Partial<T> you're telling it that everything is optional, meaning that x.a is a number | undefined and x.b a string | undefined. You should either not annotate x or annotate it with Omit<T, 'c'> so that x.a and x.b can keep their types.

See this playground link and the linked q/a above for how to do this; you can use satisfies to guarantee that x is assignable to Partial<T> without widening it to Partial<T>, letting TS keep track of the actual properties in x.

@jcalz thank you , it solves my problem! Please post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it
